# scp connection to remote host times out?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, scp

So, I am trying to retrieve a file from a remote host and copy it to my local ubuntu instance. I can ssh into the remote host from my ubuntu instance just fine, but when I try to connect with scp to transfer the file I get the error "connection timed out".

I am using the following command:
`sudo scp angela@192.168.194.57:/bm/data/'2021-02-03 21.22.23 - northvancouver.pdf' /home/angela`

I think it might have to do with the firewall/security settings on the server. The server requires an ssh key to connect, which I have set up on my ubuntu instance, but if I try to connect in the same way as I do with ssh (like trying angela@buildmapperserver-arbutus which is the server name I ssh into) it does not recognize the address (which I assume is because you need to exclusively use an ip address with scp?)

I don't know what the issue is or how to fix it. We have a github repository synced to the server and I would just push the files to the repo as a shortcut, but some of the files are too large for that.

Any ideas? If you need more information, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to successfully connect to the remote server using the command below?

```
ssh angela@192.168.194.57
```

If the `ssh` works, then check the firewall settings. It may be blocking the file transfer protocol.

Comment: Yeah I was able to successfully connect using that. However, I fixed my issue by using sftp instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using sftp instead of scp works so I am doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the path to the key

```
scp -i path/to/private/key user@ip:source/path target/path
```